# Unable to stream live audio from mic to remote port in PyAudio

Tags: audio-streaming, pyaudio, kaldi

I have a transcription server listening for audio on a port on a remote machine. Everything works If I stream a pre-recorded audio file and stream it to the port using `netcat`

I'm not able to do same using mic as input. I'm trying the following but for some reason audio is not getting streamed or I can't see and transcriptions happening or maybe I'm not sure how to get the response back in python

```
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 16000
CHUNK = 4800
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "recordedFile.wav"
device_index = 1
audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

HOST = 'ip'
PORT = 5000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

index = (input())
print("recording via index "+str(index))

stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE, input=True,input_device_index = 1,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
print ("recording started")
Recordframes = []

for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
     s.sendall(data)
    Recordframes.append(data)
print ("recording stopped")
```

Not sure how to get back response or is there some other problem. Using `Kaldi's online2-tcp-nnet3-decode-faster` in backend